# KEY_WOW64_32KEY and KEY_WOW64_64KEY

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, registrykey, registry-virtualization

Apart from the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I want to know what these keys do? Does **KEY_WOW64_32KEY** means that a 32-bit app on x64 OS will access the **WOW64 Registry Tree** ? And does **KEY_WOW64_64KEY** means that a 32-bit app on x64 OS will access the normal Registry Tree and not the **WOW64 Registry Tree** ? What if I have to access some keys which I do not know whether lies in the WOW64 or normal Registry Tree ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` on a 64-bit OS means that *the registry access, no matter if it's a 32 or 64 bit process*, will access the 64 bit registry view.
- `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` on a 64-bit OS means that *the registry access, no matter if it's a 32 or 64 bit process*, will access the 32 bit registry view.
- Neither of them have any effect on a 32-bit OS.
- Leaving the flag out (the default) on a 64-bit OS will send registry accesses from 32-bit processes to the 32 bit registry view, and accesses from 64-bit processes to the 64 bit registry view.

For more info, [this reference page at Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.110).aspx) should tell the whole tale.

Comment: According to the reference you have provided, RegDeleteKey can not be used to access the alternate registry hive. What if platform = x64, app = x86, RegOpenKeyEx with samDesired as KEY_WOW64_64KEY and I pass the handle of the opened 64Key to RegDeleteKey, would it delete the specified key then?

Comment: @user1696837 Yes, if you have an already opened HKEY to the 64-bit registry, RegDeleteKey will work (for now). If that's guaranteed to be the case in the future, I don't know, the recommended way would definitely be RegDeleteKeyEx with the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked reference:

> For more information, see [Accessing an Alternate Registry View.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Which says:

- KEY_WOW64_64KEY: Access a 64-bit key from either a 32-bit or 64-bit application.
- KEY_WOW64_32KEY: Access a 32-bit key from either a 32-bit or 64-bit application.

Comment: According to the reference you have provided, RegDeleteKey can not be used to access the alternate registry hive. What if platform = x64, app = x86, RegOpenKeyEx with samDesired as KEY_WOW64_64KEY and I pass the handle of the opened 64Key to RegDeleteKey, would it delete the specified key then?