# Failed to get Windows Serial Number in Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb6

I am trying to get the Windows Serial Number in Windows 7 with my VB6 application. However, it  always fails to retrieve it.

```
SScript.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductId")
```

It returns the following error:

```
Unable to open registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductId" for reading.
```

In Win XP, it will be successful to retrieve the serial number. I don't know whether Windows 7 has prohibited a VB6 application to get the Windows serial number.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Windows 7 32bit or 64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is peculiar isn't it? Try adding this const to your delcarations and **OR** the value to your open registry call. There is a very good explanation in the answer to [KEY_WOW64_32KEY and KEY_WOW64_64KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12796624/17776).

```
Private Const KEY_WOW64_64KEY As Long = &H100& '32 bit app to access 64 bit hive

Private Function GetWindowsProductId() As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim lngType As Long
    Dim lngBufLen As Long
    Dim lngRst As Long
    Dim hKeyHandle As Long

    lngRst = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_READ Or KEY_WOW64_64KEY, hKeyHandle)

    If hKeyHandle <> 0 Then
        strBuffer = String(255, vbNullChar)
        lngBufLen = Len(strBuffer)
        lngRst = RegQueryValueEx(hKeyHandle, "ProductId", ByVal 0&, lngType, ByVal strBuffer, lngBufLen)
        If lngRst = 0 Then
            If lngType = REG_SZ Then
                If lngBufLen > 0 Then
                    strReturn = Left$(strBuffer, lngBufLen - 1)
                Else
                    strReturn = "nothing was returned"
                End If
            Else
                strReturn = "there was an error"
            End If
        ElseIf lngRst = 2 Then     'the key does not exist
            strReturn = "the key was not found"
        Else  'if the return is non-zero there was an error
            strReturn = "There was an error " & CStr(lngRst) & " reading the key"
        End If
    End If

    GetWindowsProductId = strReturn

End Function
```