# Geting SQL Server instances names from registry

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have tried to get my SQLServer instances names from the registry by using this code:

```pascal
type
  TRegistryHelper = class helper for TRegistry
  public
    function ReadMultiSz(const name: string; var Strings: TStrings): boolean;
  end;
    
function TRegistryHelper.ReadMultiSz(const name: string;
  var Strings: TStrings): boolean;
var
  iSizeInByte: integer;
  Buffer: array of WChar;
  iWCharsInBuffer: integer;
  z: integer;
  sString: string;
begin
  iSizeInByte := GetDataSize(name);
  if iSizeInByte > 0 then begin
    SetLength(Buffer, Floor(iSizeInByte / sizeof(WChar)));
    iWCharsInBuffer := Floor(ReadBinaryData(name, Buffer[0], iSizeInByte) / sizeof(WChar));
    sString := '';
    for z := 0 to iWCharsInBuffer do begin
      if Buffer[z] <> #0 then begin
        sString := sString + Buffer[z];
      end else begin
        if sString <> '' then begin
          Strings.Append(sString);
          sString := '';
        end;
      end;
    end;
    result := true;
  end else begin
    result := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  cKey = '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server';
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  MyList: TStrings;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create;
  Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(cKey) then
  try
    MyList := TStringList.Create();
    Registry.ReadMultiSz('InstalledInstances', MyList);
    ListBox1.Items.Assign(MyList);
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
  Registry.Free;
end;
```

But I have noted the `iSizeInByte = -1` every time, and I failed to get those names by this way.

Also, I have noted that when trying to get those instances from my `TADOQuery` connection string builder, the component also failed to get those names.

Is there any way to get them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling your code for 32bit or 64bit?  On my 64bit machine, there is no `InstalledInstances` value in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Serve` key, but there is such a value present in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` key instead.

Comment: in my machine the value is exist in the key . Win10 . & it conatins the key value "InstalledInstances" as REG_MULTI_SZ Value .

Comment: Am compiling for 32bit.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot proving the key exists where you are expecting? Are you looking at the 32bit or 64bit view of the Registry? What is the value of the [`TRegistry.LastError`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.LastError) property when `TRegistry.GetDataSize()` returns `-1`?

Comment: I already attached the screenshot , the value for the TRegistry.LastError  is 2.

Comment: If the OS is 64 bit you need to check both 32bit and 64 bit registries since SQL Server was available in several releases for each.  So do both a `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY)` and `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_32KEY)` on 64bit Windows.  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view?redirectedfrom=MSDN and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796624/key-wow64-32key-and-key-wow64-64key

Comment: My Os is 64 bit , & you right @Brian , This solved my question.I used the `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY)` and it works . Thank you .